# Python | Web Crawlers | Am I using it right?

Tags: python, iframe, embed

So, I'm looking into Python right now, as I looked into it a long time ago, and didn't get too far into learning the languages, and now, I'm looking into it again.

What I'm looking into right now is Web Crawlers, but I'm not sure if it's the right think I'm suppose to be looking into for this project.. Please correct me if I'm wrong, but here's the project I'm having in mind

I'm wanting to code a program, where I can simply start it, and enter a website url (specific, or complete website) and it'll scan it for Embed/iFrame code, and download the link into a table such as:

- Page Title - | -# of iFrame's Found- | -Embed1- -/Embed1- | -Embed2- -/Embed2-
  and so on.

Am I looking into the right languages, and aspects, or should I be looking into something else for this?

Thank you in advance for any feedback/support!

Comment: [scrapy](https://scrapy.org/) is what you are looking for.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are multiple ways to scrape a web-site. Here is an example using `BeautifulSoup`.
You can install `BeautifulSoup` using
`pip install python-bs4` for `windows`
`apt-get install python-bs4` for `linux`

You can get started [here](http://www.pythonforbeginners.com/python-on-the-web/beautifulsoup-4-python/)

*Working Code*

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import urllib
r = urllib.urlopen('http://www.aflcio.org/Legislation-and-Politics/Legislative-Alerts').read()
soup = BeautifulSoup(r)
print soup.prettify()[0:1000]
```

Output:

```
<class 'bs4.BeautifulSoup'>
<!DOCTYPE html>
<!--[if lt IE 7]> <html class="no-js ie6 oldie" lang="en-US"> <![endif]-->
<!--[if IE 7]>    <html class="no-js ie7 oldie" lang="en-US"> <![endif]-->
<!--[if IE 8]>    <html class="no-js ie8 oldie" lang="en-US"> <![endif]-->
<!--[if gt IE 8]><!-->
<html class="no-js" lang="en-US">
 <!--<![endif]-->
 <head>
  <title>
   Access denied | www.aflcio.org used Cloudflare to restrict access
  </title>
  <meta charset="utf-8"/>
  <meta content="text/html; charset=utf-8" http-equiv="Content-Type"/>
  <meta content="IE=Edge,chrome=1" http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible"/>
  <meta content="noindex, nofollow" name="robots"/>
  <meta content="width=device-width,initial-scale=1,maximum-scale=1" name="viewport"/>
  <link href="/cdn-cgi/styles/cf.errors.css" id="cf_styles-css" media="screen,projection" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css"/>
  <!--[if lt IE 9]><link rel="stylesheet" id='cf_styles-ie-css' href="/cdn-cgi/styles/cf.errors.ie.css" type="text/css" media="screen,projection" /><![endif]--
>>>
```

You can play with the  output to filter the content you want, such as `iFrame`.
More details [here](http://web.stanford.edu/~zlotnick/TextAsData/Web_Scraping_with_Beautiful_Soup.html).

Comment: Awesome, this is exactly what I was looking for, however when I try running "pip install python-bs4" I get this error:
Could not find a version that satisfies the requirement python-bs4 (from versions: )
No matching distribution found for python-bs4

(I'm on Windows 10)

EDIT: Got it "pip install beautifulsoup4"

Comment: Glad to help. If my answer resolves your question, do you mind accepting the answer ? This way the question doesn't hang on SO as unanswered